# how to ignore entering duplicate records into database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using statement

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO return_routes (busNumber, stop_id) VALUES ('" . $busNumber ."',". $stop_id . ")";
```

But I find that same(duplicate) stop_id values are inserted into table multiple times. How to restrict that.

Comment: Do you have UNIQUE constraint on stop_id?

Comment: From the mysql manual "If you use the IGNORE modifier, ignorable errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors generate warnings instead."

Answer (score 0):

use UNIQUE constraint,

OR Check previous Records to check combination like :

store values in Variable
Check Before running Insert Query
select * from return_routesTable where busNumber = "$new_Instered_Bus_number" AND stop_id ="$new_Stop_ID"

> if record exist { $record_History = 1;} else { $record_History = 0;}

> Now run if( $record_History = 0) { run insert query Code } else { "give warning/error text for user"}